# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mamp

Exact Error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 20

I'm completely new to SQL and PHP, so as part of an assignment I was asked to edit a mentor's code and insert into my project. However, when I run the code, it comes up with an SQL syntax error at line 20 (which is where the `<body>` tag opens). Could someone please help me pinpoint the error? I'm really new to this stuff, and I'm sorry in advance if this is seen as "rude" or if I'm wasting your time <3.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>"Sign Up" Form:</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper style1">
            <section id="main" class="container">

                <?php
                    //-------------------------------------------------
                    $firstNameVal = 'Insert First Name';
                    $lastNameVal = 'Insert Surname';
                    $usernameVal = 'Choose a Username';
                    $passwordVal = '-------';
                    $emaiAddresslVal = 'Insert email';
                    $addressVal = 'Insert Address';
                    $suburbVal = 'Insert Suburb';
                    $ageVal = '17';

                    //-------------------------------------------------



                    //database credentials
                    define('DBHOST','localhost');
                    define('DBUSER','root');
                    define('DBPASS','root');
                    define('DBNAME','Login');

                    //new database connection
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                    //if form has been submitted process it
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        // ???
                        $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

                        //collect form data
                        extract($_POST);

                        //very basic validation
                        if($firstName ==''){
                            $error[] = 'Please enter a first name.';
                        }
                        if($lastName ==''){
                            $error[] = 'Please enter a last name.';
                        }

                        if($username ==''){
                            $error[] = "Please enter a username";
                        }
                        if($password ==''){
                            $error[] = 'Please enter a password';
                        }
                        if($emailAddress ==''){
                            $error[] = 'Please enter an email address.';
                        }
                        if($address ==''){
                            $error[] = "Please enter your address";
                        }
                        if($suburb ==''){
                            $error[] = 'Please enter your suburb.';
                        }
                        if($mobile ==''){
                            $error[] = 'Please enter your personal mobile  number.';
                        }
                        if($age == ''){
                            $error[] = 'Please enter your age!';
                        }
                        if(!isset($error)){

                            try {

                                //insert into database
                                $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user(
                                firstName, 
                                lastName, 
                                username,
                                password,
                                emailAddress,
                                address,
                                suburb,
                                age,
                                mobile) 
                                VALUES (
                                :firstName, 
                                :lastName, 
                                :username, 
                                :password, 
                                :emailAddress, 
                                :address, 
                                :suburb, 
                                :age, 
                                :mobile, 
                                ');
                                $query->execute(array(
                                    ':firstName' => $firstName, // processes the values for each form field
                                    ':lastName' => $lastName, //
                                    ':username' => $username, //
                                    ':password' => $password, //
                                    ':emailAddress' => $emailAddress, //
                                    ':address' => $address, //
                                    ':suburb' => $suburb, //
                                    ':age' => $age, //
                                    ':mobile' => $mobile, //
                                ));

                                //redirect to index page
                                header('Location: success.php');
                                exit;
                                // if error, it displays error
                            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //check for any errors
                    if(isset($error)){
                        echo '<section id="content" class="box" style="background-color: #F4CDCD;">';
                            echo '<h3>Errors</h3>';
                            echo '<b><ul>';
                            foreach($error as $error){
                                echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
                            }
                            echo '</ul></b>';
                        echo '</section>';
                    }
                ?>

                    <form method="post">

                        <!-- Your Details -->
                        <section id="content" class="box">
                            <h3>Your Details</h3>
                            <div class="row uniform 60%">
                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['firstName'];}?>" placeholder="First Name" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['lastName'];}?>" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row uniform 60%">
                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="username">username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username'];}?>" placeholder="Userame" />
                                </div> 
                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="password">password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['password'];}?>" placeholder="Password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row uniform 60%">

                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="emailAddress">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['emailAddress'];}?>" placeholder="jane.doe@compuhyperglobalmeganet.com" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['mobile'];}?>" placeholder="1234 567 890" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="age">Age</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['age'];}?>" placeholder="17" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row uniform 60%">

                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['Address'];}?>" placeholder="21B Baker Street" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
                                    <label for="suburb">Mobile</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="suburb" id="suburb" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['suburb'];}?>" placeholder="marylebone" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </section>

                        <br>
                        <!-- Submit Button -->
                        <section id="content" class="box">
                            <div class="row uniform 60%">
                                <div class="12u">
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li style="width: 100%; list-style: none; ">
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Finish and Submit" style="width: 100%;" />
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                    </form>

            </section>
        </div>

    </div>
<!-- Scripts -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `:mobile,` << it's a typo

Comment: Fred means the "extra" `,`. mysql isn't so gracious on excepting that unlike PHP or javascript.

Comment: However, on the downvote.. for a new user the code is properly formatted and everything needed to solve it is there. I personally only downvote effortless questions like the downvote button suggests: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`

Comment: You shouldn't use `extract` on user provided data. `$password` should be hashed. `Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET, $_FILES, etc.).` http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Also, @chris85 what do you mean not use extract()? what should I do instead? Also, what do you mean $password should be hashed and how should I do that? Sorry I really have no clue what you mean ^_^

Comment: @ShreySomaiya Why are you using `$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );`?? And what Chris means is that you store a password into a database in plain text. Don't tell me you were completely unaware of this? `password_hash()` && `password_verify()`

Comment: @Xorifelse i have no idea what that line does, it's my teacher's code I'm merely adapting it to suit my database for my assignment.  I was completely unaware of this, but i have gone and constructed a random hashing algorithm so that the password is not stored as plain text every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the last `,` comma from the SQL statement and try again. That means change this:

```
//insert into database
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user(
firstName, 
lastName, 
username,
password,
emailAddress,
address,
suburb,
age,
mobile) 
VALUES (
:firstName, 
:lastName, 
:username, 
:password, 
:emailAddress, 
:address, 
:suburb, 
:age, 
:mobile, 
');
```

to this:

```
//insert into database
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user(
firstName, 
lastName, 
username,
password,
emailAddress,
address,
suburb,
age,
mobile) 
VALUES (
:firstName, 
:lastName, 
:username, 
:password, 
:emailAddress, 
:address, 
:suburb, 
:age, 
:mobile
');
```

Comment: Thank You!! I also needed to put a bracket after the comma after mobile  and it worked!!